# Powershell TextBox SecureString

Tags: powershell, securestring

Is it possible using the `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` (or any other method) to enter in text that can then be converted to securestring?  I would like to be able to take a value entered, convert it to securestring and write that to a file which could then be called on if needed and the securestring converted back should we need to identify the value.

I've looked into something similar to this, but since I am using the TextBox forms, I don't want to rely on Read-Host

```
$secstr = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter your text"

$secstr | ConvertFrom-SecureString | out-file C:\temp\test.txt

$secstr = get-content c:\temp\test.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlaintText -Force
```

Essentially, I want to have a text box use masked/password characters (which I can do with `$TextBox.PasswordChar = "*"` and then take that input and dump it into a securestring text file.  Then, I could use another script to call on that file and display the text in plain text for the end user should they need to know that current value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a regular `TextBox` if you want to embed this in a custom GUI:

```
Add-Type -Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms'

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form

$password = New-Object Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$password.PasswordChar = '*'
$password.Top  = 100
$password.Left = 80

$form.Controls.Add($password)

$form.ShowDialog()
```

[[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/3aeb2e94-1610-4342-8bcf-a645ab462721/powershell-how-to-mask-text-entry-in-a-powershell-forms-box?forum=ITCG)]

and then convert the text to a secure string:

```
$secstr = $password.Text | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlaintText -Force
```

If you just want to prompt for credentials you could use [`Get-Credential`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849815.aspx), which already stores the entered password as a secure string:

```
PS C:\> $cred = Get-Credential

Cmdlet Get-Credential an der Befehlspipelineposition 1
Geben Sie Werte für die folgenden Parameter an:
Credential
PS C:\> $cred.Password
System.Security.SecureString
```

Answer (score 1):

An additional way is to use a plain TextBox and as Ansgar mentioned use the PasswordChar attribute:

```
$textbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Textbox
$textbox.Size = '75,23'
$textbox.PasswordChar = '*'
$form.Controls.Add($textbox)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Form and then add the password input box
This is how I would do

```
Add-Type -Assembly Name System. Drawing
Add-Type -Assembly Name Presentation Framework
Add-Type -Assembly Name System.Windows.Forms

$Form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = 'Password'
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,230) 
$Form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
```

Following will create OK button on the form

```
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,150)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult =[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$Form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$Form.Controls.Add($OKButton)
```

Do the same for Cancel button if you need it.

Create a Label before Text box as follows

```
$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 40)
$label.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$label.Text = 'Password' 
$form.Controls.Add($label)
```

Following will Create the Masked Text box for password entry.

```
$Textbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$Textbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$Textbox.PasswordChar = "*"
$Form.Controls.Add($Textbox)
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thank you Dennis for making the code presentable. I was struggling with that